# ¿Cómo generar botones con tamaño fijo?

Tags: java, java-swing

En lenguaje Java y usando NetBeans actualmente tengo un JFrame que contiene un JPanel(panel) y un JButton (agregar) y estoy usando una lista de botones.

Ahora uso un GridLayout, el problema que tengo es que si tengo un solo botón, genera automáticamente uno muy grande y su proporción queda muy mal, quisiera que cada botón se cree con un tamaño fijo de digamos (80,50).

Éste es el código del evento del botón agregar:

```
private void botonAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

    JButton boton = new JButton("boton"+indice);
    //boton.setSize(80,50)
    panel.add(boton);
    botones.add(boton);
    indice++;
    panel.updateUI();

}
```

Creo el botón y lo agrego a mi JPanel (panel) pero por más que yo le dé un tamaño no me deja, ¿de qué forma puedo hacer esto o en qué estoy fallando?

Comment: En lugar de agregar directo el JButton agrega el JButton en un JPanel o usa mejor GridBagLayout

Comment: Creo que con esto lo solucionarías boton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(ancho, alto));

Answer (score 1):

Fija la dimension maxima y la dimension de preferencia. Esto es aplicable a todos los componentes swings.

```
boton.setMinimumSize(w, h);
boton.setMaximumSize(w, h);
boton.setPreferredSize(w, h)
```